# WCF service with SSL and Microsoft WCF Service Host

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I have been following the Microsoft instructions on [how to Configure an IIS hosted WCF service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service-with-ssl), amongst others.

But first things first I want to get the service running locally in Visual Studio successfully first and tested using the Microsoft WCF Service Host.

Any pointers to a better article or way to get this working?

```
<services>
  <service name="DMD.WcfService.MeetingDataService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="DMD.WcfService.IMeetingDataService" bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/DMD.WcfService/MeetingRepositoryService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
 <bindings>  
  <basicHttpBinding>  
    <binding name="secureHttpBinding">  
      <security mode="Transport">  
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>  
      </security>  
    </binding>  
  </basicHttpBinding>  
</bindings>
```

System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].